# Spare us of the vote reminder

Tags: feature-request, moderators, election

I have voted for the Stack Overflow moderator election and although I did, today I got a reminder bar up in the screen when I visited Stack Overflow. Why?

Comment: Does it keep popping up when you close it once?

Comment: Have you clicked on the [x] that is on the right?

Comment: @Brad : Having had the info stored there (that I've voted) it shouldn't have prompted in the first place.

Comment: @Downvoters : provide reasons for the downvotes. If you lack courage please create a fake account and then post from that account.

Comment: Why not downvote for a short line when the entire bulk of your request or reasoning is in one of the comments?

Comment: +1.  This may be a one-off and it may be easy to dismiss it with one click.  But zero clicks is better than one.  If it's fixable why not fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we are lazy.

Comment: good call Andrei. I got the same treatment when complaining about the "got flair?" constant reminder. and I also keep getting the vote reminder, and clicking the X each time it pops up (every page) is not a workable solution.

Comment: amazingly, it stopped popping up around the same time as I posted the above message. so maybe a bug was discovered and silently fixed.

Comment: Maybe. I've seen silent bug fixes like this in other websites before.

Answer (score 6):

All users with rep > 200 got the notification.

It's a one time thing so feel free to dismiss it with *extreme prejudice*, chuck norris style.

Comment: Dear Jeff, please read my comment left on o.k.w.'s answer.

Comment: I may sound annoying and bitter but I am just trying to help to build a better SO..

Answer (score 3):

Picture says a thousand words...

[image: Close voting bar for good, click X]

Comment: +1 for embracing the true spirit of Meta. Freehand circles are salvation! Walk slowly, into the **light!**

Comment: @SOTU, I've learnt it the hard way months ago :P

Comment: No people, I am sorry but you don't get it. When I voted my identity has been known. Somewhere has been stored the info that I have voted for this election. The very same site then asked me to vote later although I was still logged in. It could have checked if this user voted or not in this election and IF I HADN'T then it would have been normal to nag me.

Comment: @Andrei, I do get it. I was kinda irritated by it as well, but if clicking the close button does the job, I'm happy. Maybe the next time there's an similar announcement, this can be improved.

Comment: exactly, o.k.w., "this can be improved". I didn't say it is a tragedy, it is a **SMALL** annoyance, barely feelable..

Comment: @Andrei, the above 'SMALL' in your comment is the only time you mentioned the 'smallness' of it, perhaps the guys felt your tone/words in the original post might be too 'serious'? Anyway now all is clear :)

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear enough..

Comment: Maybe my tone was not constructive. I will try to be better next time.